# Storing object with different parameters multiple times in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a list of shops that I get from an API. Each one has different ID and name (along with other parameters). The users can log in in each one of them and when they do, they need to stay logged in, no matter what, until they log out eventually. What I thought of was, to save the number/id of the shop in SharedPreferences and log the user in. Then, when I do the checking if the user logged in, I check if the shop number saved in SharedPreferences is the same with the number/id of the shop they are currently in. If so, they are logged in, if not they are not logged in. The problem is that if they log in to another shop, the SharedPreferences would be overridden with the number/id of the other shop. So, basically, this way they can only be logged in in one shop. How can I make it that I each shop in SharedPreferences and somehow check to see if they are logged in in the right shop afterwards?

**Logging in Shop**

```
@Override
public void loginShop(final Shop shop, UserInfo userInfo, final Callback<Shop> callback) {
    ShopLoginBody body;
    body = map(shop, userInfo);
    mCallLogin = App.getRestClient().getApiService().shopLogin(body);
    mCallLogin.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ShopLoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ShopLoginResult> call, Response<ShopLoginResult> response) {
            int loginNumber;
            int customerNumber;
            Result<Shop> result = new Result<>();

            if (response.code() != 200) {
                try {
                    JSONObject objError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    Error error = new Error();
                    error.setErrorMessage(objError.getString("errorMessage"));
                    error.setErrorCode(objError.getInt("errorCode"));
                    callback.onFailure(error);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            }

            loginNumber = response.body().getLoginNumber();
            customerNumber = response.body().getCustomerNumber();

            mPreferenceAdapter.writeShopNumber(shop.getId());
            mPreferenceAdapter.writeLoginNumber(loginNumber);
            mPreferenceAdapter.writeClientNumber(customerNumber);
            mPreferenceAdapter.writeIsLoggedIn(true);
            mPreferenceAdapter.apply();

            shop.setLoginId(loginNumber);
            shop.setCustomerId(customerNumber);
            ShopRepository shopRepository = new ShopRepository();
            shopRepository.updateLoginNumber(shop);
            result.setData(shop);
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ShopLoginResult> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

**How I check later on**

```
    isLoggedIn = mPreferenceAdapter.readIsLoggedIn();
    shopNumber = mPreferenceAdapter.readShopNumber();
    if (shopNumber == mShop.getId() && isLoggedIn) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_login).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_login).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout).setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is not the best storage for your data structure, I guess. But to solve your situation you can, though, serialize your list of logged-in shops to JSON string and then store it into preferences.

Say

`prefs.edit().putString("auth-shops", new Gson().toJson(shops)).apply();`

Comment: That way, how can I know which one was clicked and logged into, and also, how can I delete that particular one when the user logs out?